# how to get this fib sequence to start at 0?

Tags: python

so I have this sequence running from 1 to 21. but I need it to start at 0.

```
nbr1 = 0
nbr2 = 1
i = 0

for i in range (0, N):
   tmpnbr = nbr1
   nbr1 = nbr1 + nbr2
   nbr2 = tmpnbr
   print (nbr1)
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to get it start at 0 zero. any ideas?

Comment: hmm... add `print(0)` ?

Comment: move your print statement to the top of the loop

Comment: Start with `nbr1 = 1` and `nbr2 = -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want

```
for i in range (0, N):
   print (nbr1)
   tmpnbr = nbr1
   nbr1 = nbr1 + nbr2
   nbr2 = tmpnbr
```

instead of

```
for i in range (0, N):
   tmpnbr = nbr1
   nbr1 = nbr1 + nbr2
   nbr2 = tmpnbr
   print (nbr1)
```

So that you print the 0 first instead of the 1. You are printing only after you've added to the first number. You want to print the first number first, and then the following numbers.

Comment: does this really require an answer?... (not the downvoter...)

Comment: Not the dv'er either, but this is so basic, that I wish people would comment and vote to close instead.

Comment: because you shouldn't encourage such low quality questions by answering them.

Comment: Also, if you're going to write an answer, you may as well fix the other problems... no 0 needed in `range`, and they could just do `a, b = b, a + b` instead of whatever it is they're doing now, etc.

Comment: How is this a low-quality question? OP is probably learning how to code and doesn't understand why it starts at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: "learning" supposes a minimum of effort which the OP obviously hasn't even bothered considering. And despite SO is not supposed to be a place to learn the basics.

Comment: @Mast3r_Heath: Its great that you are trying to learn and everyone here to help you. The issue is that your question was already answered in the comments and does not need an "official" stack overflow answer. Nothing wrong with you asking questions. 

lets close this question, as it has been answered!

Comment: @HarshdeepSokhey "lets close this question, as it has been answered"? What? That's not how it works. Also, shouldn't you argue against those *comments*, as stackoverflow instructs us to avoid answering questions in comments?

Comment: SO also instructs us not to entertain questions that show lack of research. Ideally, the question should have been downvoted (as it has been done) as it is not constructive! The conversation can go on forever and I was trying to save everyone's time. Peace!